# TZDateTime Flutter dart

Tags: flutter, timezone

How do i do if i want to convert 12H the 24h of tz.TZDateTime on flutter this is my code :

i have an output 2023-07-13 09:23:00.000-0400 and i want 2023-07-13 09:23:00 PM or AM

```
tz.TZDateTime _converTime(int hour, int minutes) {
  final tz.TZDateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
  tz.TZDateTime scheduleDate = tz.TZDateTime(tz.getLocation('America/New_York'),
      now.year, now.month, now.day, hour, minutes);
  if (scheduleDate.isBefore(now)) {
    scheduleDate = scheduleDate.add(const Duration(days: 1));
  }
  return scheduleDate;
}
```

convert 12H the 24h of tz.TZDateTime on flutter

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

So let's assume you have this result ***2023-07-13 09:23:00.000-0400*** then
lets say we convert that result to string so something like this e.g.

```
    final String currentDateString = "2023-07-13 09:23:00.000-0400";
    // Note: HH:mm:ss 24 hr format
    // And for 12 hr is hh:mm:ss 
    // and "a" is indicate PM or AM
   final format = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a").format(DateTime.parse(currentDateString));
    print(format); // result 2023-07-13 01:23:00 PM
```

try this on dart pad to see the actual result